# SyntaxError when running with Python 2

Tags: python, syntax, terminal, ipython

I have a Python script called "controlled_biomass_exp.py" that generates some data and plots it. Its over 100 lines long so I don't want to dump it all here.

I can run it from Ipython in the terminal once and it works fine. If I repeat the command to run the script again with:

> In [3]: run controlled_biomass_exp.py

I get:

> File "< ipython-input-3-3ec3d096e779>", line 1
>
> run controlled_biomass_exp.py
>
> ```
>                      ^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

(The carrot is pointing at the last letter of the filename, "p".)

I get the same problem if I run any other python script after running this one. If I quit Ipython in the terminal and restart it the problem "re-sets". I can run other scripts fine, until I run the broken one once. I haven't encountered a problem like this before. Any help directing me where to look for solutions much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with iPython but does your script contain a run function? One that overrides the original.

Comment: Hi Rik. The script doesn't contain any run functions.

Comment: Hi Daniel, in that case, maybe you could post the code so we can check for problems there.

Comment: Have you tried to use `python` instead of `run` ? open terminal and enter `python controlled_biomass_exp.py`. Of course you have to be in directory where this file located

Comment: Thanks Rik, micgeronimo. I can see now you were both pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your script `controlled_biomass_exp.py` overwrites `run` in your current namespace.

This toy example will produce a similar problem:

```
# file: test.py
run = "hello world!"
print(run)
```

Calling `run` in IPython is just a shortcut for `%run` which is a built-in magic function. Once you overwrite `run` (e.g. as shown in my toy example) you cannot use the shortcut anymore.

However, `%run controlled_biomass_exp.py` should still work for you.

Comment: Thanks cel. This was exactly the problem. I knew it would be something daft. I had a loop of "runs" with a variable "run". Once I changed the name of this, everything is awesome!